# Can i deploy my php project with gitlab ci to remote host WITHOUT Docker images?

Tags: php, jenkins, ssh, deployment, gitlab-ci

We have `PHP` project on gitlab. I can deploy it using `Jenkins` + `Phping` to remote host, but `Jenkins` run slow often. I see many examples with `Gitlab-ci` and `Docker` images, but  I don't want to use `Docker` images. I just want to git clone this project to remote host after some jobs triggers and to make some jobs after this on remote host. I saw `gitlab-ci` runners `ssh` and `shell`, maybe it makes using one of this runners?

Can i deploy my `PHP` project with gitlab ci to remote host **without** `Docker` images? Will be it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it few weeks ago.
In that case I was using `gitlab-ci` with the `shell` runner, it worked fine for me. I had some problems with ssh keys, but I fixed it reading a little:

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

and

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically

So, yes you can deploy it this way and it's fine to do it.

I'm adding a `.gitlab-ci.yml` that I used to deploy a `jar` application.

```
image: JAVA:latest 

before_script:
  - /home/leandro/netbeans-8.2/java/maven/bin/mvn clean install

after_script:  

stages:
  - build_deploy_dev
  - build_deploy_production   

build_&_deploy_dev:
  stage: build_deploy_dev
  except:
   - master
  script:
   - cd target
   - scp EnviaEmail-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar root@192.168.0.147:/home/leandro/Desktop
   - ssh root@192.168.0.147 "kill $(ps -ef | grep EnviaEmail | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}') < /dev/null > /home/leandro/Desktop/KillEnviaEmail.log 2>&1 &"
   - ssh root@192.168.0.147 "java -jar /home/leandro/Desktop/EnviaEmail-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -Xmx256m < /dev/null > /home/leandro/Desktop/EnviaEmail.log 2>&1 &"
```

Hope it helps